# Finding a basis for the vector space of the complex numbers.

Tags: vector-spaces, complex-numbers

How do I find a basis of the vector space of the complex numbers when the scalars are real numbers and when they are complex?

Comment: How do you represent a typical complex number? Your answer to this question should tell you how to answer the first of your questions.

Comment: There is no such thing as "**the** base".

Answer (score 2):

If $\mathbb{C}$ is considered as a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ than it has dimension $d=1$ and any non zero complex number can be a basis: a standard basis is the number $1\in \mathbb{C}$.

As a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{C}$ has dimension $d=2$ and any complex number $a+ib$ can be identified with the couple of real numbers $(a,b)$ , so we can use as a basis the couple of couples as $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$, where $(1,0)$ is identified with  $1 \in \mathbb{C}$ and $(0,1)$ is identified with $i \in \mathbb{C}$ .

Comment: Any _non-zero_ complex number can be a basis over $\mathbb C$. This is mathematics we're doing here!

Comment: Sorry !!! I edit.